# Issue in creating video from array of image

Tags: iphone, video, avassetwriter

I used the following code to generate the video from array of images and audio (pre recorded)..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imagearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Quiz pic1.jpg",@"Quiz pic2.jpg",@"Quiz pic3.jpg",@"Quiz pic6.jpg",@"Quiz pic7.jpg",nil];
    image1array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<[imagearray count]; i++)
    {
        UIImage *aimage=[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [image1array addObject:aimage];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",image1array);
    ImageVideoPath=@"/Users/image/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/6CC91208-5819-4BFF-B868-6605887861EB/Output";
    FinalVideoPath=@"/Users/image/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/6CC91208-5819-4BFF-B868-6605887861EB/VideoOutput";
    CGSize size;
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:0]];
    size=image.size;
    NSString *audioFilePath;
    int duration=10;
    //[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[image1array objectAtIndex:0] CGImage]];
    [self writeImageAndAudioAsMovie:image andAudio:audioFilePath duration:duration];

    //[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[image CGImage] andSize:size];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)writeImageAndAudioAsMovie:(UIImage*)image andAudio:(NSString *)audioFilePath duration:(int)duration {
    NSLog(@"start make movie: length:%d",duration);
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:ImageVideoPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                              error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:ImageVideoPath]) 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:ImageVideoPath error:nil];

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.width],AVVideoWidthKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,nil];
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
    writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter setShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse:YES];
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    //Write samples:
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage];
    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];

    //Finish the session:
    [videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(duration, 1)];
    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];

    CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);
    [videoWriter release];
    [writerInput release];
    audioFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Video" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSLog(@"%@",audioFilePath);
    [self addAudioToFileAtPath:ImageVideoPath andAudioPath:audioFilePath];
}

-(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image{
    float width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    float height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width,height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,(CFDictionaryRef)options,&pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata,width,height,8,4*width,rgbColorSpace,kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0,width, height), image);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}

-(void) addAudioToFileAtPath:(NSString *)vidoPath andAudioPath:(NSString *)audioFilePath{
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",ImageVideoPath,audioFilePath);
    NSURL* audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
    NSURL* video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ImageVideoPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",video_inputFileUrl);
    NSString *outputFilePath = FinalVideoPath;
    NSURL* outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

   AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
NSLog(@"asset:%@",videoAsset);
NSArray *tracks1=[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([tracks1 count]>0)
{
    //CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack=[tracks1 objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:videoAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];  

}

NSArray *tracks = [audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
if([tracks count]>0)
{
    AVAssetTrack * audioAssetTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                                   preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioAsset.duration) ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];  


    //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);
    [audioAsset release];audioAsset = nil;
}


    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];   
    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         switch (_assetExport.status) 
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 //export complete 
                 NSLog(@"Export Complete");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 //export error (see exportSession.error)  
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 //export cancelled  
                 break;
         }
     }];    
}
```

I found that one of the video file is created from the method `writeImageAndAudioAsMovie` but itz nt supporting any player in my machine...
I don't knw wat I'm missing? Any suggestions plz....

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies at two places :

1.The path you are providing should be something where you are allowed to write like documents directory. And it must have some specific extenstion. As you are creating HighestQualityVideo so it should be .mov.

2.You should provide proper outputFileType should be as per extension and presetType. so in your case it should be `_assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;`.

Try with these changes.

**Update:**
To remove the crash you need to replace code for `AVAssetTrack` with following code in `addAudioToFileAtPath` method:

```
NSArray *tracks = [videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
if([tracks count]>0)
{
AVAssetTrack * audioAssetTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                                preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];  


    //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);
    [audioAsset release];audioAsset = nil;
}
```

Regarding video types:

Facebook supports QuickTimeVideo(mov/qt) see http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=218673814818907

To support other type of videos you will need to change the `presetName` while creating `AVAssetExportSession` object and extension of output file for this please go through this document.

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=AVAssetExportSession++class&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2FDOCUMENTATION%2FAVFoundation%2FReference%2FAVAssetExportSession_Class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=xXxPT5akDsG8rAeck5XUDQ&usg=AFQjCNH1HqxIiT1kYJom6kZ82NS-qjVSyQ&cad=rja

**Update 1:**

Here we are accessing each image and appending it to buffer after displaying some time(I have divided duration.

```
for (int i=0; i<[image1array count]; i++)
    {
        int time = (int)i*(duration/[image1array count]);
        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[image1array objectAtIndex:i] CGImage]];
        [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(time, 1)];
    }
```

**Update 2:**

Here is the code that I in which I have made few changes to compose a mixed asset.

```
-(void) addAudioToFileAtPath:(NSString *)vidoPath andAudioPath:(NSString *)audioFilePath{

    NSURL* audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
    NSURL* video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ImageVideoPath];
     NSURL* outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:FinalVideoPath];
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVAsset * audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];;
    AVAsset * videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                                preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                                preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL ok = NO;

    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVAssetTrack *sourceVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    ok = [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
    if (!ok) {
        // Deal with the error.
        NSLog(@"Error : %@ : %d",error,videoAsset.duration.value);
    }
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    ok = [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
    if (!ok) {
        // Deal with the error.
        NSLog(@"Error : %@ : %d",error,audioAsset.duration.value);
    }

    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];   
    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         switch (_assetExport.status) 
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 //export complete 
                 NSLog(@"Export Complete");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 //export error (see exportSession.error)  
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 //export cancelled  
                 break;
         }
         NSLog(@"Error : %@",_assetExport.error);
     }];    
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for ur rply.....Bt if the video is in AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie I taught I ll ve pblm in playing tat video in facebook....

Comment: I too get SIGABRT in the `AVAssetTrack` in `addAudioToFileAtPath`

Comment: Please see updated answer. I have updated about crash as well as about the video support.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions,bt still I ve the pblm tat video file is generated bt i can't see any video bt i can hear the audio...I don't knw wat I'm missing...

Comment: And even quick time player is nt able to read tat format,bt vlc player is reading tat...

Comment: I thnk the pblm is in `writeImageAndAudioAsMovie` as I can't gt the proper video output.....

Comment: Yes, I also feel so because here we want to use image array to create video but we are using single image with presentation time for buffer as 0.

Comment: In writeImageAndAudioAsMoview I have change few line so its creating video with the images now. see the code in updated answer.

Comment: Hey dude I ve a query in tat.. U ve used duration itz just an integer value,will the compiler ll automatically convert it to seconds?

Comment: seconds is a measurement unit, we can express its value in int, double, long. But here in case of CMTime we need int_32 for the value of start time that is why I am typecasting it.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. To make this work you will need to delete existing files from the documents directory else it will give error(can not save files).

Comment: I feel tere is no pblm in tat `addAudioToFileAtPath`the pblm is only in `writeImageAndAudioAsMovie` since I can't able to get the proper video file....

Answer (score 0):

One thing that caught my eye was that you're calling `CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);` in your `writeImageAndAudioAsMovie:andAudio:duration:` method but since you didn't create `adaptor.pixelBufferPool`, you don't own it and therefore shouldn't be releasing it, right? Seems suspect to me.